# Clear ASP required field validator error messages based on validation group

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

In one aspx page, there are 8 textboxes and have corresponding ASP required field validators. First four required field validators belong to one ValidationGroup and the rest belongs to another ValidationGroup. There are two Submit and Clear buttons as well. On Clicking the first clear button I am clearing the first four set of textboxes from JavaScript.

Along with that I want to clear the error messages of the required field validators belonging to "group1" ValidationGroup from JavaScript.

So how to clear the validation Error messages corresponding to one ValidationGroup?

Comment: @AmitKumar I am not permitted to upload any kind of code. Against the policy.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provided your code so i assumed the id of your submit button is **Button1**
and add class to each required field validator of group 1 (let class name **reqgr1**)
.and also you have tried it using jquery, so posting my answer in jquery.
just like

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Req1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="fitext" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="g1" class="reqgr1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Button1').on('click', function () {              
                  $('.reqgr1').html('');
             });
        });
```

this will remove error message of those required field validator.as these rquired field validator are converted into span tag after rendering.

Comment: I have already tried this approach and felt like this is not an optimum solution. Suppose I have 10 or 20 RequiredFieldValidator, then I have to hardcode all those IDs in JavaScript. Can I write some code using the ValidationGroup name so that the code have a better readability?

Comment: This code has one issue. After executing the above JS, the validation is not working any more. I think its better to hide it rather than clear the content with html('')

Comment: @VishnuY: this is working fine. you can check by removing class from one requiredfieldvalidation. it will show you validation error message.